# How to set log level in log4j from properties file in runtime

Tags: logging, log4j, jvm-arguments

How do I set log level in `log4j.xml` using properties file in `runtime time`?

```
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
               value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] [%t]: %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="com.mypackage" additivity="false">
    <level value="${level}" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</logger>
```

I set the value of `$level` from my `vm arguments` by passing the value as `-Dlevel="warn"` so that all messages with level warn and above got logged.

Now my problem is I have to set the value of log level from a `properties` file instead of `vm arguments` ? How can I do this?

P.S : I am using common.logging in the java code with log4j as a configuration mechanism.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I am assuming that you want to set the logging level package-wise programmatically but you want to put that into the log4j properties file?

Comment: @Neeraj I want to specify logging level from a properties file (specific to my application , Not log4j.properties) and set this value in the log4j.xml (which i am using to configure the logging in my application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the way to change log level dynamically:

```
LogManager.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```

To use a property from custom file use [Properties.loadFromXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML%28java.io.InputStream%29) to read a file with properties, then determine a level using these properties.

Comment: That is a good suggestion . But No way of picking it in the xml from a properties file?

Comment: Well, just read your custom file with properties and use this property to set a new level. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML(java.io.InputStream)

Answer (score 2):

Sam,

I am not sure what you are asking for is the default behaviour for log4j. What you can do is,  add properties like log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG in your application properties file and point log4j to use your application properties file as the log4j properties file.

You can force log4j to take its configuration file by specifying the following vm argument:

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=resources/log4j_dev.properties
```

OR

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/resources/log4j_dev.properties
```

An example of log4j properties file is as follows:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

You can also use xml format for the properties file.

If you want to add loggers for log4j programmatically (on rumtime), this is what you would need to do:

```
 ConsoleAppender console = new ConsoleAppender(); //create appender
  //configure the appender
  String PATTERN = "%d [%p|%c|%C{1}] %m%n";
  console.setLayout(new PatternLayout(PATTERN)); 
  console.setThreshold(Level.FATAL);
  console.activateOptions();
  //add appender to any Logger (here is root)
  Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(console);

  FileAppender fa = new FileAppender();
  fa.setName("FileLogger");
  fa.setFile("mylog.log");
  fa.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"));
  fa.setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
  fa.setAppend(true);
  fa.activateOptions();

  /add appender to any Logger (here is root)
  Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(fa)
  //repeat with all other desired appenders
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would like to set level of logger during run time . I am using log4j.xml as configurator to configure logging in my application

Comment: @Sam Edited the answer to include programmatic config.

Comment: I dont want to add loggers. I just want to set level for logging to `info` or `warn` or `fatal` based on the user's preference at runtime

Comment: No my case is that i want to `set the log level in a properties file and pick it up in log4j.mxl not using java code`

Comment: so I think Logger.setLevel method might help. The loophole is, even if you change the logging level in the xml file on runtime, it might not be straightforward to ask Logger to get the settings from the xml file once the application has already started.

Comment: So there are no way of setting value to logger during startup of application other than setting it in java code or editing it properties file?

Comment: Yes. Or else you write a shell script which will take a value from command line and edit the properties file for log4j before trigerring the java command which will start the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can set log level in System.setProperty by reading from your dynamic  properties file and it will be reflected in log4j.

Cheers!